# How to convert array of errors to JSON in Go

Tags: arrays, json, go, error-handling

I have an array of errors (type of error), but when I try to return the client in JSON format, it arrives empty.

**It was created this way:**

```
var (
    ErrEmptyName = errors.New("Nome não pode ser vázio")
    ErrInvalidType = errors.New("Tipo de pessoa inválido")
)

func (p Person) Validate() []error {

    var errors []error

    if govalidator.IsNull(p.Name) {
        errors = append(errors, ErrEmptyName)
    }

    if p.Type != "F" && p.Type != "J" {
        errors = append(errors, ErrInvalidType)
    }

    return errors
)
```

**In my Controller:**

```
err := person.Validate()
c.JSON(422, gin.H{"errors" : err})
```

**My Output:**

```
{"errors":"[{}]"}
```

Answer (score 7):

The [`error`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error) type is an interface with a single `Error()` method, but it is not special to the `json` package (the `Error()` method is not called on it).

However, `error` values may hold values of static types which may be nicely marshalable, or they may define their own marshaling logic by implementing [`json.Marshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler). Simply converting an `error` to `string` by calling its `Error()` method means we're not honoring the custom marshaling logic.

So I would suggest to create our own error slice type, on which we can implement our marshaling logic which should be:

- check if the error value implements `json.Marshaler`, and if so, let it marshal itself
- else as a fallback case call `error.Error()` to "obtain" a `string` which can easily be marshaled

This is how it could look like:

```
type JSONErrs []error

func (je JSONErrs) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    res := make([]interface{}, len(je))
    for i, e := range je {
        if _, ok := e.(json.Marshaler); ok {
            res[i] = e // e knows how to marshal itself
        } else {
            res[i] = e.Error() // Fallback to the error string
        }
    }
    return json.Marshal(res)
}
```

And this is how you can use it:

```
err := person.Validate()
c.JSON(422, gin.H{"errors" : JSONErrs(err)})
```

Let's test our `JSONErrs`. We're also use a custom error type which implements custom marshaling logic:

```
type MyErr struct{ line int }

func (me MyErr) Error() string { return "Invalid input!" }

func (me MyErr) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(
        struct {
            Type, Error string
            AtLine      int
        }{"MyErr", me.Error(), me.line})
}
```

And the test code:

```
errs := []error{
    errors.New("first"),
    errors.New("second"),
    MyErr{16},
}

data, err := json.Marshal(JSONErrs(errs))
fmt.Println(string(data), err)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/NSyMcwlLXm)):

```
["first","second",{"Type":"MyErr","Error":"Invalid input!","AtLine":16}] <nil>
```

Answer (score 2):

An `error` type is an interface which must implement an `Error()` method that returns an error message as a string. This is defined here: https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#error. The reason why the `error` type is an interface, is to allow for `error` types that can be type casted to retrieve more detailed information.

Functions like `fmt.Println` and `log.Println` automatically resolves `error` types to display the message from `Error()`, the JSON library however, does not. The simplest way to get around this problem is by converting the error messages in `[]error` to a `[]string` and encoding that.

Here's some example code to do that with a for loop.

```
errs := person.Validate()
strErrors := make([]string, len(errs))

for i, err := range errs {
    strErrors[i] = err.Error()
}

c.JSON(422, gin.H{"errors" : strErrors})
```